# Where can I report bugs relating to Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I'm looking for either an URL with a feedback form or an email address.

Comment: Have you tried the feedback form at the bottom of every page ?

Comment: At the bottom of the page I only see "Change background image"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for something, for example *Webapps*, and then click on the `Send feedback` at the bottom of the resulting page. The rest is up to you ;)

Resources

- [Report a problem with Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6223687?hl=en)

Comment: I wonder why they don't link to this feedback form on the contact page (at least I couldn't find it)

Comment: For Support control , Majority of support can be answered through google.com/support faq. Its the same reason why it is hard to find the contact info on facebook/support site

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google no longer shows the "Give us feedback" link at the bottom of search results, so you will have to bookmark the link provided by Mr. Palavuzlar. There is also an unofficial bug tracker here:

https://code.google.com/p/googlebugs/